# How can any of answers be correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, volume

[image]

Blue and orange curves are isotherms and I need to compare changes in Interal energies. In processes 1->2 and 2->3

I have options:

A) same value and same sign

B) almost same value

C) different signs

D) different values

Now, my question is: if processes are isothermal and there is no change in Temperature and therefore no change in internal enery, how can any of answers be correct?

Is this some kind of mistake by the author?

Apparently the correct answer is C.

Comment: Temperature change from 1 tp 2 is T2-T1.  Temperature change from 2 to 3 is T3-T2.  But T3=T1 (isotherm). Therefore, (T3-T2) = -(T2-T1).  So the internal energy changes are opposite in sign.

Comment: But 1st proces is isobaric and 2nd is isohoric. In 1st we have work done and heat exchanged and in 2nd only heat. Shouldn't change in internal energies be different?

Comment: For. an ideal gas, internal energy is a function only of temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processes are not isothermal, because they do not follow the isotherms.

Comment: Blue and orange curves are isotherms and therefore proces is isothermal.

Comment: @jeaq The process $1\rightarrow 2$, which is represented by the purple horizontal line connecting point $1$ to point $2$, is pretty clearly not along an isotherm.

Comment: You are right. I got it completely wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Should i delete question?

Comment: @jeaq No, you shouldn't delete questions which have been answered.

Comment: Oh, okay. I just thought that It's not really worth keeping it, since it doesn't really explain much but my confusion with the question.

Comment: @jeaq For that reason, the community may vote to close it. If you would prefer to delete it, you will have to un-accept my answer, then remove your upvote (I assume you voted for my answer). Once that's done, you will be able to delete your question.